# Dialog not showing on full screen in Landscape in android.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

On my **`OnListItemClick`** , i am displaying a **`Dialog`** which is working fine i.e. displaying on fullscreen in **`Portrait Orientation`** using custom layout for dialog. To support LandScape Orientation, i have added that custom layout in **`layouts-land`** folder and the device is picking that layout. But the dialog is not being shown on full screen horizontally. its only filling vertical screen.

```
    final Dialog prfDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    prfDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    prfDialog.setContentView(R.layout.view_student_dailog_layout);
    prfDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.dialoge_back);
```

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/editStudentMainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

             // Other View

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make another class which extends Dialog, and add this

```
    @Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null)
    {
        int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
    }
}
```

This will force the dialog to be fullscreen.

Maybe if you want want to do this, just use that method after creating your dialog.

Comment: This was the solution for me. Setting in every possible way BEFORE onStart() was called would not work; waiting until the onStart was called however allowed this to successfully resize. Thank you.